# What is the subject of the “sizzled”?

Tags: subjects, participle-clauses

I don’t understand what is happening to the following sentence, especially “ that sizzled for a split second”

I read this on Kimutatu Tokyo university English reading (キムタツ東大英語リーディング), an English textbook written in Japanese for college entrance exams.

The sentence is underlined in the picture.
[image]

> “At this, the man coughed and walked over to a can of water, throwing something into that sizzled for a split second.”

I think that “throwing” is a participial and “that” means “a can of water”. Then what the subject of the “sizzled?”
I know the cigarette made the noise. But I have no grammatical idea about the subject of “sizzled”

Comment: There is an error in the sentence. A possible correction is: " ... throwing something into **it** that sizzled ... ".

Comment: I agree with the last comment. It makes no sense. The preposition should be "in", not "into".  The subject of "sizzled" would then be "something". Another possibility is that the word "it" is missing: "... throwing something into **it** that sizzled for a split second". This version would also have "something" as subject of "sizzled".

Comment: Beware that 'textbook'.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's 100% an error but it's certainly non-standard. The noun following a preposition can sometimes be omitted in casual speech (and in some dialects people will form what might be non-standard phrasal verbs that way e.g. "Can you come into?" meaning "Can you come inside/into the building?"), but this text appears to be more formal.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and commenting a lot. Because many answered and commented, it is diffIcult for me to reply all of them, I read and learn a lot from all comments. I now understand what I couldn’t know but for you. I admire you all  with special reverence.

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be **in** instead of **into**:

> At this, the man coughed and walked over to a can of water, throwing something in<strike>to</strike> that sizzled for a split second.

Or it could be missing **it**:

> At this, the man coughed and walked over to a can of water, throwing something into **it** that sizzled for a split second.

In both cases, **something** is what sizzled.

Comment: Since it's from a test and is underlined, I wonder whether this sentence is the subject of some question like "Where is the error in this sentence?"

Comment: Yes, from the previous Q&A, the underlinded section has to be translated to Japanese for the test.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the word "into" is a mistake.  You should therefore be cautious about using this book for learning English.

The fix is to use "in" to form a verb phrase "throwing {something} in" or to use a pronoun "it":  "throwing {something} into it".

The word "that" is a marker of the relative clause.  You could slightly rephrase as :

> ... throwing {something that sizzled for a split second} in.

Here you can see that the subject of sizzled is understood to be "something".  The relative clause has been moved to the end, after in, because it is a long phrase, and long phrases are often moved to the end of clauses, when grammatically possible.

The word "that" isn't a pronoun, and so doesn't mean "can of water".